# How can I zip multiple files without the origin file extension being included?

Tags: command-line, batch, 7-zip

I'm trying to zip multiple files but keep coming up with this problem that my code obviously doesn't work for. Here is the code:

`for /r %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X"`

I'm trying to 7z multiple files in a directory but I keep getting my files in a format like "Foobar.txt.7z" but instead I would like it to be "Foobar.7z" I have thousands of files and I know this would be an easy fix I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the full file name with the .7z extension in your command. Let's stop doing that:

```
for /r %X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%~nX" "%X"
```

EXPLANATION:
You are using DOS variables. %X is the variable. There are variations in DOS to manipulate variables. The "~n" expresses the filename from the variable without the extension.

FROM: https://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm

> %~nI  expands %I to a file name only

Answer (score 1):

#### I keep getting my files in a format like "Foobar.txt.7z"

```
for /r %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X"
```

You need to remove the extension from `%%X`. You can do this using the expression `%%~nX`:

```
for /r %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~nX.7z" "%%X"
```

However, if you do this, you may have a problem if there are multiple files with the same name but different extensions. For example, in my test directory I have files with the following names:

```
> dir /b test.*
test.cmd
test.ps1
test.sh
test.txt
```

Using the following in a batch file:

```
for /r %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~nX.7z" "%%X"
```

Will produce the following for the above files:

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.7z" "F:\test\test.cmd"
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.7z" "F:\test\test.ps1"
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.7z" "F:\test\test.sh"
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "test.7z" "F:\test\test.txt"
```

You will need to figure out a way of dealing with any such duplicate archive names unless adding multiple files to the same archive is your intention.

From the command line you can replace `%%` with `%`, as follows:

```
for /r %X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%~nX.7z" "%X"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: That code doesn't run and it's because you only need one "%" and not 2. The error is `%%X was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @HackSlash It works in a batch file, which is what the OP was using. Answer updated.